# I want to navigate between screen in react native and I want to do it in an external appNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Here is what I tried so far:

```
function SplashNavigator() {
  // not hitting this function
  return (
    <SplashStack.Navigator >
      {console.log("SplashNavigator")}
      <SplashStack.Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreen} />
    </SplashStack.Navigator>
  )
}

  function AuthNavigator(){
  return(
    <AuthStack.Navigator >
      <AuthStack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
      <AuthStack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
      <AuthStack.Screen name="ForgotPassword" component={ForgotPasswordScreen} />
    </AuthStack.Navigator>
  )
}
 function MainNavigator(){
  return(
    <MainStack.Navigator >
      <MainStack.Screen name="OrderPlaced" component={orderPlaced} />
      <MainStack.Screen name="ProductDescription" component={ProductDescriptionScreen} />
      <MainStack.Screen name="CartegoryProductListing" component={CategoryProductScreen} />
      <MainStack.Screen name="Delivery" component={DeliveryScreen} />
      <MainStack.Screen name="OrderHistory" component={OrderHistoryScreen} />
      <MainStack.Screen name="CancelledOrderHistory" component={CancelledOrderHistory} />
      <MainStack.Screen name="FinishedOrderHistory" component={FinishedOrderHistory} />
      <MainStack.Screen name="EditProfileScreen" component={EditProfileScreen} />
      {/* <MainStack.Screen name="HomeStack" component={HomeStack} /> */}
      <MainStack.Screen name="Payment" component={Payment} />
      <MainStack.Screen name="HistoryDetails" component={HistoryDetails} />
      <MainStack.Screen name="CustomerCareSupport" component={CustomerCareSupport} />
      <MainStack.Screen name="Address" component={Address} />
      <MainStack.Screen name="AddEditAddress" component={AddEditAddress} />
      <MainStack.Screen name="Cart" component={CartScreen} />
    </MainStack.Navigator>
  )
}

function AppNavigator(){
  return(
    <NavigationContainer>
      {/*It is Reaching here*/}
      <AppStack.Screen>
        {/*it is reaching here*/}
        <AppStack.Screen name='SplashNavigator' component={SplashNavigator}/>
        <AppStack.Screen name="AuthNavigator"   component={AuthNavigator} />
        <AppStack.Screen name='MainNavigator'   component={MainNavigator} />
      </AppStack.Screen>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )  
}
export default AppNavigator
```

But it is not working it is hitting the app navigator but it is not even rendering if I give a screen directly insted of a function.

What else can i do to navigate through these pages.
and also i want to navigate to the authnavigator and the mainNavigator if only the user is exsisting.

And I want to do the check in the splash Screen.